# php security courses

Tags: php

I got asked today by my boss if I wanted to do some php security courses, however I am not even sure other than the zend securing php applications course if any exist could any one provide any links or details, also would it be worth looking at CISSP ?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only [PHP security course](http://software-security.sans.org/courses/description/secure-coding-php-developing-defensible-applications-1117) that I've heard of. I know of the author (Johannes Ullrich) and he's excellent but then he's not always the instructor. Here's a complete list of [SANS web app](http://software-security.sans.org/events/) sec courses since that's the topic you're essentially asking about.

Regarding CISSP, I decided not to go for it, it just wasn't for me. I felt it was too general and too high-level so I went and did a few [SANS courses](http://www.sans.org/security-training/courses.php) and certifications. SANS courses are much more technical and well-respected, though they do seem more popular in the US than say, Europe. I've heard mixed reports about CISSP but I'm not in a position to comment further.

There's loads of courses and certs out there so you need to have think about what you want to do, what technology you'd like to work with etc and go from there.

I'm not a huge fan of vendor courses/certifications so try to stick to something independent and that's useful across multiple jobs/industries.